# How many isosceles triangles with total side length $100$ are there?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, problem-solving

Let the sum of the three sides of a triangle be $100,$ and all the sides are positive integers length, how many possible isosceles triangles are there?

Comment: Hint: count solutions to the (in)equations $2a+b=100$ and $2a \geq b$.

Comment: @DanielFranke $2a>b$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** We can certainly do $(49,49,2)$, $(48,48,4)$, $(47,47,6)$ and so on for a while. But the sum of the two equal sides cannot be less than or equal to the third side. That should tell you where we need to stop.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Let the side length $=x$, then we know the base length $=100-2x$. Then set up your inequality(s).

Answer (score 0):

x=2*a+100-2*a if (100-2*a)

2*34+32=100
2*35+30=100
2*36+28=100
2*37+26=100
2*38+24=100
2*39+22=100
2*40+20=100
2*41+18=100
2*42+16=100
2*43+14=100
2*44+12=100
2*45+10=100
2*46+8=100
2*47+6=100
2*48+4=100
2*49+2=100
number of solution: 16

Comment: How will the side lengths $1,1,98$ form a triangle?

Comment: thx , i forgot something